# AS3: Reset variables and repeat part of function

Tags: actionscript-3

This is a class of my schoolproject but it doesn't work right now. http://pastebin.com/0K9H6wAi

I have a frog who blinks 3 times and than moves - so far, so good.
But when it has moves it has to blink again and move again, and i cant figure this out. This happens in line 109 till the end.

```
package  {

        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.events.Event;
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;
        import flash.utils.Timer;
        import flash.events.TimerEvent;
        import flash.geom.Point;

        public class KikkerOgen extends MovieClip {

                var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 4);
                var geknipperd:int = 0;
                var hoevaakKnipperen:int = 0;
                var aantalGezwommen
                var score:int = 0;

                //boompjes en bosjes
                var object_1:Point = new Point(57,84);
                var object_2:Point = new Point(500,86);
                var object_3:Point = new Point(46,168);
                var object_4:Point = new Point(479,126);
                var object_5:Point = new Point(69,159);
                var object_6:Point = new Point(443,162);
                var object_7:Point = new Point(248,316);
                var object_8:Point = new Point(209,198);
                var object_9:Point = new Point(163,357);
                var object_10:Point = new Point(440,283);

                //constructor
                public function KikkerOgen()
                {
                        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Update);
                        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, isClicked);
                        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, Knipperen);
                        timer.start();
                        gotoAndStop(13);
                }

                public function Update (event:Event)
                {
                        trace(currentFrame);
                }

                //Score moet bij deze functie omhoog - document class
                public function isClicked (event:MouseEvent):void
                {
                        this.parent.removeChild(this);
                }

                //Hier telt hij het aantal keren dat de kikker moet  knipperen
                function Knipperen (event:TimerEvent):void
                {
                        if (event.currentTarget.currentCount >= 2 && geknipperd < 3) {
                                geknipperd ++;
                                gotoAndPlay(1);
                        }

                        //Wanneer de kikker 3x geknipperd heeft moet hij naar een nieuwe positie
                        if (geknipperd == 3)
                        {
                                //Selecteer een random positie om heen te zwemmen
                                switch(Math.round(Math.random() * 10))
                                {
                                        case 1:
                                                x = object_1.x;
                                                y = object_1.y;
                                                break;
                                        case 2:
                                                x = object_2.x;
                                                y = object_2.y;
                                                break;
                                        case 3:
                                                x = object_3.x;
                                                y = object_3.y;
                                                break;
                                        case 4:
                                                x = object_4.x;
                                                y = object_4.y;
                                                break;
                                        case 5:
                                                x = object_5.x;
                                                y = object_5.y;
                                                break;
                                        case 6:
                                                x = object_6.x;
                                                y = object_6.y;
                                                break;
                                        case 7:
                                                x = object_7.x;
                                                y = object_7.y;
                                                break;
                                        case 8:
                                                x = object_8.x;
                                                y = object_8.y;
                                                break;
                                        case 9:
                                                x = object_9.x;
                                                y = object_9.y;
                                                break;
                                        case 10:
                                                x = object_10.x;
                                                y = object_10.y;
                                                break;
                                }
                                trace("posX:"+x);
                                trace("posY:"+y);
                                //Reset de timmer, het knipperen en laat hem opnieuw tellen om te verplaatsen.
                                geknipperd = 0;
                                trace(geknipperd);
                                timer.reset();
                                aantalGezwommen ++;
                        }
                }

                //Wanneer de kikker 3x is verplaats verwijder hem uit het spel
                function removeKikker ()
                {
                        if (aantalGezwommen == 3)
                        {
                                this.parent.removeChild(this);
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Any idea what goes wrong here?

Comment: Please post the code _on_ the site. That's why they added code formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `timer.reset();` which stops the timer but doesn't start it again.

```
Stops the timer, if it is running, and sets the currentCount property back to 0, like the reset button of a stopwatch.
```

[Timer @ AS3 reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html)

After you reset the timer, be sure to start it again with `timer.start();`

Comment: Thanks, been looking way to long at this.